# Sumar dos horas en Java

Tags: java, time

Estoy utilizando java y tengo el siguiente escenario.

La entidad temporada uno de los atributos es duracion y una temporada puede tener muchos capitulos, por cada capitulo que se agrega a una temporada, se suma la duracion de todos los capitulos y se agrega a la temporada.

Estoy realizando lo siguiente:

```
 res.getTemporada().setDuracion(res.getTemporada().getDuracion() +  res.getDuracion());
```

A la duración de la temporada:

```
res.getTemporada().getDuracion()
```

Le sumo la duración que traigo de la vista del nuevo capítulo, pero no funciona la suma de esta forma convencional

```
res.getDuracion()
```

La duración son de tipo Time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La verdad la clase `Time` no es conveniente para el uso que le estás dando. Si bien time significa tiempo, la traducción correcta para su uso sería hora.

Por ejemplo una clase `Time` no puede reflejar una duración que excede las 24 hs.

Para guardar la duración de los capitulos de una serie una medida conveniente pueden ser los minutos que duran, y eso se puede acumular tranquilamente en un `int`. Por ejemplo 80hs serían `80*60 = 4800 minutos`.

Después podés usar una función que devuelva el tiempo como String haciendo el paso inverso. Por ejemplo `4826 minutos` son:

```
int hh = (int)(4826 / 60); // 80
int mm = 4826 % 60;  // los 26 minuto adicionales de la fracción
```

Y lo podes mostrar como: `String.format("%02d:%02d", hh, mm);`